# Resolve id before loading component

Tags: angular, rxjs, es6-promise

**Using:** Angular 5

In our application we have a `storeId` that is used to fetch store specific data.

This `storeId` is used a lot when making `http` calls to our backend. 
Sometimes we have it as a url route *endpoint.dev/stores/10* and sometimes as a query param *endpoint.dev?storeId=1*

So it would be nice to simple call it using ex: `storeService.storeId`

A user can **switch store** by *changing address*, *authorize* and more...

The problem with my current solution (redux store):

1. At **startup** the app will set a default `storeId`.
2. When a **user authorize**, we will change the state to use a different storeId based on a http call.
3. After authorization a **redirect** is performed and the new page starts to load.

If the new page starts to render before the `storeId` state has changed we will get the wrong http response.

How do we make sure that the rendered page ONLY executes http calls with the members storeId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do we make sure that the rendered page ONLY executes http calls with the members storeId?

By not routing away until you got the response. So, for example, in your authorization you do this:

```
this.api.authorize()
  .do(storeId => this.storeService.setStoreId(storeId))
  .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(...));
```

This is of course pseudo code with a lot of assumptions since you haven't shared any code; either way, the gist of it is that you just chain routing away to after you actually updated the ID.